# Turn html elements visible as a sequence with pauses using jquery / js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-animate

I've been searching for quite a while now, and before everyone hits me the setTimeout() function, hear me out.

I have ~20 HTML elements which are invisible. I want them to turn visible one at a time, with a pause inbetween. I also want to use some of jQueries awesome animation features when turning them visible.

So basically I want to "play a sequence of frames/events/states" using JavaScript/jQuery.

**What have I looked in to?**

**SetTimeout():**

I've been looking at the JS setTimeout function, and from what I can tell, it works great when you have 1-3 setTimeout() functions.

If you want more, it starts to get extremely messy. They are embedded, you have to time everything by adding numbers together and it's really hard to get the overall picture.

**jQuery.delay()**

Also, the jQuery.delay() function lacks to actually pause the code. I have 20+ elements, not one I want to animate.

**Updatepanel spam**

Another option, which I kind of considers right now (please, kill me), is using an updatepanel. Every second it makes a postback using a timer, and using a session, it knows exactly at what "frame" it is. Then it can set things visible/invisible depending on frame number, and also fire jQuery animations.

Now, when I woke up this morning, I didn't dream of spamming my webserver with an updatepanel like this.... So:

Is there any good ways to do this? I am very open to suggestions.

Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Are you trying to make each element appear at it's own specified time, or can they go in order with a certain fixed amount of time in between each?

Comment: Mike: It's fine with a fixed amount of time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you apply the same class to all the elements (`sequential_expose` in my example), you can select those elements and call `each()` on the selection.  To stagger the fade in of the elements, you can multiple the index of the item as provided from `each()` and multiply it by the time you want for for the delay between fadeIn's and pass that value as parameter to `delay()`.  Given an interval of 500 milliseconds (you can make this whatever you want), the first item in selection would have `0` as delay, the second `500`, the third `1000`, etc.  You then just chain your preferred animation (`fadeIn(200)` in my example) after the call to `delay()`.

```
$(function () {
    $('.sequential_expose').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(i*500).fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

Note the example shows this as a document onready function, you can obviously change this as needed.

Comment: Nice! Much "jQuerier" than mine! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks. I personally have really tired to move my js development more along those lines and away from mixing traditional js techniques with jQuery where it makes sense.

Comment: One question: would this set `elements.length-1` timers at once? I'm not sure how `.delay()` is implemented, and having multiple timers seemed to be one of the OP's concern. My Frankenstein version, on the other hand, only has a single timer running at any given time.

Comment: @bfavaretto It would in essence do as you say and have `elements.length-1` "timers" initiated right up front.  The each loop would execute and start all elements into their respective delay/animation paths all up front. It's not like you have to manage these timers, so I don't know what the issue would be with it. I thought his concerns with managing multiple timers was more related to trying to do that with `setTimeout()` where I think your solution does a good job of eliminating that concern.

Comment: That is one amazing answer, thanks a lot! I would also love to hear the answer to bfavaretto's question - quite interesting

Comment: @Mike You're right. I misread the question and thought the OP was talking about performance, which *might* become an issue if there are too many timeouts. And LOL, I just realized it's `elements.length` timers, not `-1`. I guess i've been writing too many `foo` loops!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would use `setTimeout` for this:

```
// Assume your target elements are all divs 
var elements = $('div');

function showOne() {
    // Fade-in the first element
    elements.first().fadeIn(200);

    // Remove first element from our jQuery object
    elements.splice(0,1);

    // If there are further elements, start a new timer
    if(elements.length) {
        setTimeout(showOne, 500);
    }
}

// Start first timeout
setTimeout(showOne, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uRwFK/

Comment: You could avoid splicing, in this particular case, by using `elements.filter(':hidden').first().fadeIn(200)` -- http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/uRwFK/3/

Comment: @Blazemonger That's a nice option if you plan on reusing the same jq object later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that suggestions, that would also have solved the problem perfectly :-)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) includes a **complete** callback that allows you to chain animations.

Let's say you have an array of 20 DOM elements, here is a rough snippet:

```
var elArray=[el1,el2,...el20];

function animateFunction(i) {
    $(elArray[i]).animate(
       ...
       // on complete move to the next element
       complete: function(){if (i<elArray.length-1) animateFunction(i+1);}
    });
}

animateFunction(0);
```